# How to get data from DBF using VBA in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, connection-string, dbf

I have made an MS Access application and I use a variety of APIs to get data from other applications on the server. The new integration I am working on has DBF files but there is no support from the company relating to how to access the data (it is okay to do, but no support for it).

The DBF files, I have been told, are FoxPro. I have tried doing the import DBase but I am getting an error

> `Wrong format`

I've tried looking in different places and found a DBF viewer which does open the files.

I can't figure where to start on this. For example, do I just use a connection string of some sort and an ODBC (Fox Pro seem to be outdated and I can't find one)

Would I then use this conn string on a pass-through query?

Sorry I sound vague, but I have no idea where to start on actually implementing this feature in my app, after dealing with such well organised API systems!

Comment: What research have you done on this issue? Perhaps this will help https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/importing-dbf-file-into-access-2016/e4bd52cb-56d9-4b16-917f-cc15398f7dc3

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
Once again, the first link @June7 I still receive the "External  table is not in the expected format"
The second option is more about converting this file to a readable file.

What I am after is to read and query the file, not manipulate it.  It can be done as other companies do it... I just can't seem to find the OLEDB or ODBC

Comment: Issue in second link is same as yours - Access cannot read the file - and offers a possible cause.

Comment: Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/office/troubleshoot/access/fails-connecting-foxpro-databases